# date.toLocaleString(options) does not work javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am quite new to JS and need some help.

I want to format date with the help of toLocaleString(). According to standards first argument 'locales' can be omitted. My code looks like:

```js
    let myDate = new Date(2014, 0, 30)
    let options = {
                year: '2-digit',
                month: '2-digit',
                day: '2-digit'
            };
    let formattedDate = myDate.toLocaleString(options);
    
    console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: You need to pass a locale to toLocaleString. Use this `let formattedDate = date.toLocaleString('en-US', options);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you can skip the first argument, without supplying something for it in your case, you won't get the `options` argument to give you the results you want.

Here are a few versions of working code:

```js
let date = new Date(2014, 0, 30);

let options = {
            year: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            day: '2-digit'
        };

console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-us', options));
console.log(date.toLocaleString(undefined, options));
console.log(date.toLocaleString(options));

options.timeZone = 'UTC';
options.timeZoneName = 'short';

console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', options));


// sometimes even the US needs 24-hour time
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour12: false }));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not understand that without locales the function will not work properly it is not so clear from specification.

Comment: The reason that you don't "get the `options` argument to give you the results you want" is because the options given are not a valid "locale".

Comment: The name of the first option, "locale", is a misnomer in the spec. It's actually a language code.

Answer (score 5):

The first argument to [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) is not optional, but you can pass `undefined` to it.

```js
let date = new Date(2014, 0, 30)
let options = {
            year: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            day: '2-digit'
        };
let formattedDate = date.toLocaleString(undefined, options);
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: The first argument **is** optional. It says this right in the link you provided. Yes, you can pass `undefined` to it, but you don't have to.

Comment: No, you can't omit the first argument without also omitting the second argument. Your own answer shows a full date for your third console.log on Chrome. The syntax shown in the link is `[locales[, options]]`, which means locales only, locales and options, or neither. If locales was optional as you claim, it would be `[[locales],[options]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `options` as second parameter:

```
let date = new Date(2014, 2, 2)
let options = {
            year: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            day: '2-digit'
        };
let formattedDate = date.toLocaleString(undefined, options);
```

Comment: You can omit the first argument.

Comment: Not so much. You cannot use `options` as the first argument, that's exactly what lessismore tried.

Comment: Actually, you can. You just won't get the expected results. The first argument **is** optional. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Well, lessismore was asking for a 2-digit dateTime, which you edited yourself. I guess she is asking for a working solution, rather than a theoretical discussion on whether `options` can be used as a first argument?